# Multi user login with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying a multi user login with firebase. I am using cloud firestore and while signup for both users, I sent their respective role to database. While logging in, I get those role and tried to login with their respective role. 
**In detail:**
I have two users Student and Teacher. While registering both users, I send role to their databases. In login activity, I got their role in a string and set the condition If role == "Student" sign in to Student Dashboard. If role == "Teacher" sign in to Teacher Dashboard.

**Error**
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference.
This is my Login Activity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText editText_email, editText_password;
        Button loginButton;
        TextView textView_newUser;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        FirebaseFirestore firestore;
        String studentRole, teacherRole, userID;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            editText_email = findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
            editText_password = findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
            loginButton = findViewById(R.id.signIn_button);
            textView_newUser = findViewById(R.id.textView_newAccount);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

         /*   studentRole = getIntent().getStringExtra("Student");
            teacherRole = getIntent().getStringExtra("Teacher");*/



            userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("Teacher Database").document(userID);
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(LoginActivity.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    teacherRole = documentSnapshot.getString("Role");

                }
            });

            DocumentReference documentReference1 = firestore.collection("Student Database").document(userID);
            documentReference1.addSnapshotListener(LoginActivity.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    studentRole = documentSnapshot.getString("Role");

                }
            });


            textView_newUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String email = editText_email.getText().toString();
                    String password = editText_password.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please fill the required fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else{
                        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful() && firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                                            if (teacherRole.equals("Teacher")) {  // Getting Error in this line
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged In Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TeacherDashboardActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                            else if (studentRole.equals("Student")){ // Getting Error in this line
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged In Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentDashboardActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Logging in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });

                    }


                }
            });
        }
    }

2020-06-06 21:11:06.721 21714-21714/com.example.findustaadfyp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.findustaadfyp, PID: 21714
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.findustaadfyp.LoginActivity$4$2.onComplete(LoginActivity.java:101)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: The above method won't work because firebase send asynchronous calls.

Comment: teacherRole variable is not getting initialized before the login check occurs

Comment: You can quick fix it with `if ("Teacher".equals(teacherRole) ` and `if ("Student".equals(studentRole)` (known as [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)), but that means the user may have to reclick the buttons.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I could not find the correct answer